# how to write an algorithim to swap two variables without creating the third variable?

Tags: algorithm

how to swap two variables without creating the third variable? for ex. a=10 b=20 so, how can I write an Algorithm to swap these two variable to a=20 b=10 without adding another variable c in my logic?

Comment: There is no need to devise your own 'Algorithm'. In this case, you can just try to use language feature in Python: >>> a, b = b, a

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this technique

```
a=a+b
b=a-b
a=a-b
```

Edit 1:
As commented by pjs, the above technique could overflow in some languages so you can use XOR:

```
a=a^b
b=a^b  ## which is b= (a^b)^b=a
a=a^b  ## which is b= (a^b)^a=b
```

Comment: In many languages that could overflow.  Use XOR instead (if the operands are integer).

Comment: @pjs it overflows but it still works.  In languages where it doesn't overflow, though, you can lose bits.

Answer (score 0):

`int x = 987, y = 123;`

`x = x xor y;`

`y = x xor y;`

`x = x xor y;`

Now x and y are swapped:
`x = 123, y = 987;`